# Google URL shorten decode android

Tags: android, google-url-shortener

I have a shorten url done by http://goo.gl/
I need to get the original url. Is there any api to do that in ANDROID.

What I tried for make shorter -

> compile 'com.andreabaccega:googlshortenerlib:1.0.0'

```
GoogleShortenerPerformer shortener = new GoogleShortenerPerformer(new OkHttpClient());

String longUrl = "http://www.andreabaccega.com/";

GooglShortenerResult result = shortener.shortenUrl(
    new GooglShortenerRequestBuilder()
        .buildRequest(longUrl)
    );

if ( Status.SUCCESS.equals(result.getStatus()) ) {
    // all ok result.getShortenedUrl() contains the shortened url!
} else if ( Status.IO_EXCEPTION.equals(result.getStatus()) ) {
    // connectivity error. result.getException() returns the thrown exception while performing
    // the request to google servers!
} else {
    // Status.RESPONSE_ERROR
    // this happens if google replies with an unexpected response or if there are some other issues processing
    // the result.

    // result.getException() contains a GooglShortenerException containing a message that can help resolve the issue!
}
```

Comment: For what I got the negative vote man?

Comment: If you can't help please don't give a negative vote.There is not relevant solution I searched almost 2 hours that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made my solution. **What I did -**

I open a webview without visibility then call that url.Then on page load complete I a fetching the url

```
WebView webView;
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.help_webview);
webview.loadUrl("http://goo.gl/tDn72f");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    String myResult = webView.getUrl();
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Load the ShortURL with a `HttpURLConnection`, then you can read out the target URL with

```
httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("location");
```

---

**Full solution**

```
URL url = new URL("http://goo.gl/6s8SSy");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Log.v("Full URL", httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("location"));
```

Can't test live right now, but this should be working.

Comment: Can u give full solution?